# Dynamic SQL SELECT Statement with PHP based on user options

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

First of all I want to mention that I've been trying and searching like crazy to find a solution to this but no luck so far. My issue is the following:

I have a MySQL database with dozens of rows and I created a jQuery grid to display the data; this page is working already. 
As per requirements I'm putting together a page where people can select a couple options from checkboxes and filter the results. This is how it will work:

Page 1 will have 3 groups of checkboxes (Name, Location, Language) and each set has different options ([Name: David, Nick, etc], [Location: New York, Washington, Mumbai, London, Miami], [Language: English, Spanish]. Once the user selects his options it will submit a form with something like this

grid.php?location=Washington&location=Mumbai&language=English&name=David

Creating the string is easy but the receiver that will take this parameters and place then in an array to then create the SQL statement is where I'm struggling.

I've tried with something like this:

```
$location= $_GET['location'];
$language= $_GET['language'];
$name= $_GET['name'];

if($location!=""){
    $where[] = 'location=';
    $where_args[] = $location;
}
//same code for the other 2 options

$where_clause = implode(' OR ', $where_args);

$sql_json = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE $where_clause ORDER BY id DESC";
```

None of the options are mandatory so the query needs to accept the possibility that the value may or may not be set so it may end up being something like grid.php?language=English.

I know that the code above doesn't quite work but I will appreciate if someone can please point me in the right direction.

Comment: So, he can select more than one location? Because your form submit example shows so.

Comment: Correct. Kristen's code below works but not in my current scenario. I mentioned that not only variables can be empty (not passed) some times but also that all variables can be repeated as I'm creating a SELECT SQL statement. The variable could look as follows:

grid.php?location=Washington&location=Mumbai&language=English&name=David&name=Mario

Please note the 2 "name" variables and the 2 "location".

Kristen's code works but not in the case of an array because the last variable will override the others, meaning, I'm able to pass "Mario" but no "David". 

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the get values through $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] instead of $_GET? The $_GET way would return only the last value of one specific name. And $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] would return the whole string, which could be splitted and manipulated. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605414/php-how-to-check-if-query-string-or-post-vars-contain-same-var-twice.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing iterating through the array using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. Thanx Mt.Schneiders & @Akam, this community rocks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$location= $_GET['location'];
$language= $_GET['language'];
$name= $_GET['name'];

if($location!=""){
    $where[] = " `location` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($location)."'";
}
if($language!=""){
    $where[] = " `language` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($language)."'";
}
if($name!=""){
    $where[] = " `name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
}
$where_clause = implode(' OR ', $where);
//same code for the other 2 options

$sql_json = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE $where_clause ORDER BY id DESC";
?>
```

Comment: Guys, I was away in a conference so I haven't had the chance to try your solutions. I'm testing right now. Thanx for the help!!!

Comment: I'd change `$name = $_GET['name']` for `if(isset($_GET['name']){$name = $_GET['name']}` just for the good pratice.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just iterate through the $_GET and grab keys with values, so:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$val) {
   if ($val != "") {
      $where_args[] = "$key='$val'";
  }
} 
$where_clause = implode(' OR ', $where_args);
```

You'd probably want to do better validation than the above example, though, and you could add select/case statement if you needed to perform checks on particular values...

Comment: Guys, thanx for all the help. I'm running into another issue. 

The problem I'm facing right now is that since I'm using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to grab all values from the URL it is capturing all the extra values that jQxGrid sends extra variables: 

grid.php?location=Miami&location=Orlando&language=english&name=David&filterscount=0&groupscount=0&pagenum=0&pagesize=20&recordstartindex=0&recordendindex=18

How can I ignore those variables? I tried unset and array_diff but I'm probably not using the right syntax because none of the two worked. The extra stuff starts from &filterscount. @Akam

Comment: If you know what fields you want and they don't change, you could build an array with those fields, i.e. `$myKeysArr = array('location','language',...);` and then check that the particular key is valid by changing the line `if ($val != "") {` to `if ($val !="" && in_array($key,$myKeysArr)) {` .  Ideally, you might want to build the $myKeysArr by returning all column names in your MySql table in case you're going to be making changes to the table - or want to use this functionality somewhere else.